# How do I count the # of members that are in table A but not in table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables and want to count the number of member IDs that are in one table but not in the other.

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT u.member_id)
from database.tablea u
where u.member_id NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT member_id
  FROM database.tableb
)
```

This is taking forever and it shouldn't. Is the code OK?

If you have more efficient code please advise.

Comment: That seems a reasonable way to do what you require. Maybe you have performance issues in your database? You could remove the `distinct` from the sub-query as that might take a bit of time.

Comment: Why not just do a `LEFT JOIN` on `tableb` and select each id which has a `NULL` value for `tableb.member_id`.

Comment: @RyanWilson This could work too. Didin't think that such a simple query would load for over an hour.

Comment: @DaleBurrell You might be right with the performance issues. because the NOT EXIST solution below doesn't seem more efficient that what I wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would change this to `not exists` and recommend an index:

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT u.member_id)
from database.tablea u
where not exists (select 1
                  from database.tableb b
                  where u.member_id = b.member_id
                 );
```

Then, you want an index on `tableb(member_id)`.

If you have a `members` table, then you might find that the fastest method is:

```
select count(*)
from members m
where exists (select 1
              from database.tablea u
              where u.member_id = m.member_id
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from database.tableb b
                  where b.member_id = m.member_id
                 );
```

With indexes on `tablea(member_id)` and `tableb(member_id)` this should be pretty fast.  The only time this would not be the case is if you had zillions of members in `members` and relatively few rows in `tablea`.

Comment: Agreed, I'd prefer to use not exists. Also, it would probably be helpful to have that index on both tables.

Comment: @EilertHjelmeseth . . . An index on `tablea(member_id)` would reduce I/O bandwidth (presumably) because it is a covering index for the query.  However, I'm not 100% sure it would eliminate additional work for the `count(distinct)`.  I don't have a handy SQL Server installation to actually test that.

Comment: @EilertHjelmeseth If Im not an adminstrator. Simply a user of SQLServer, how do I add indexes?

Comment: If you do not have access to create indexes you'll either need to ask an administrator to grant you that access or ask them to create the index for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should always avoid subqueries where possible, they are in most cases slower. This should be faster:

```
select count(DISTINCT u.member_id) from database.tablea ua
left join database.tableb ub on
ua.member_id = ub.member_id
where ub.member_id is NULL
```

Comment: This was what I suggested, only thing wrong with your answer is I believe the OP wants `distinct ids` in the `COUNT`

Comment: A good read: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: `EXISTS` is likely faster in this case.  Assuming the `DISTINCT`s in OP's query are needed, then the ids are duplicated in each table.  `EXISTS` will perform a semi-join and stop searching on the first match found.  The optimizer may be smart enough to process both identically, though.

Comment: @RyanWilson Exactly. If I do not include distinct, im not getting the asnwer i want

Comment: @RyanWilson I forgot to add DISTINCT to the query, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @DaleBurrell EXPLAIN is a mysql specific construct, so I made a mistake. However, I think you knew that there is no explain button, so you're comment is just unconstructive. As is your other comment, where you are saying that there's an exception to what I already said is not 100% applicable.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I said something applies in most cases. You provided an exception. Providing an exception to something that applies in **most** of the cases doesn't make it incorrect. Regarding the duty part, I think what's important is trying to help, and I did that to the best of my knowledge. You're just being condescending.

Comment: @RaduMazilu - its not an exception - your statement "You should always avoid subqueries where possible" is untrue and misleading. There are many many cases where subqueries are in fact the best solution.

Comment: @RaduMazilu - given the complexities of SQL Server performance, all you can accurately say is "Try this query - it might be faster"

Comment: @DaleBurrell This is a much more informative and constructive argument, thank you